# Map a pandas list type column with a dictionary for two highest values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
 df
col1    col2
 A     [x,y]
 B     [z]
 C     [p,q,x,y]
 D     [q,z,t]
```

And I have a dictionary like this,

```
d={x:3, y:2, z:5, p: 4, q:7, t :6}
```

Now I want to keep maximum 2 values in col 2 based on the dictionary. So the final dataframe would look like,

```
col1    col2
 A     [x,y]
 B     [z]
 C     [p,q]
 D     [q,t]
```

I could able to do it using a for loop, mapping with the dictionary but I am looking for some pandas shortcuts to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `heapq.nlargest`:

```
from heapq import nlargest

df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x: nlargest(2, x, key=d.get))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1    col2
0    A  [x, y]
1    B     [z]
2    C  [q, p]
3    D  [q, t]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = (df.explode('col2')
      .assign(new = lambda x: x['col2'].map(d))
      .dropna(subset=['new'])
      .sort_values(['col1','new'], ascending=[True, False])
      .groupby('col1')['col2']
      .agg(lambda x: list(x.head(2)))
      .reset_index()
      )
print (df)
  col1    col2
0    A  [x, y]
1    B     [z]
2    C  [q, p]
3    D  [q, t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure pandas method. -

```
d_inv = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}

df.explode('col2')\          #Explode the list to separate rows
  .replace(d)\               #Replace the alphabets by numbers from d
  .groupby('col1')['col2']\  #groupby on col1
  .nlargest(2)\              #get top 2 largest numbers
  .replace(d_inv)\           #replace the numbers by alphabets from d_inv
  .groupby(level=0)\         #group by level 0
  .apply(list)               #apply list to reverse the initial explode
```

```
col1
A    [x, y]
B       [z]
C    [q, p]
D    [q, t]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```